# Data not displaying in executable jar file on other's computer

Tags: java, sql, swing

I have created a java desktop application and want to run executable jar on user computer but on users computer jar file is executing but data is not displaying in it.
I have created a bridge to relate data from sql to my application on user computer and have also installed jdk and jre..

Same jar file is working fine on my Pc.

If someone have any idea about it kindly share..

Comment: *"If someone have any idea about it kindly share.."*  Make sure the code dumps the stack trace or logs the exception in every catch then run it from the command line to collect the data on the failure.  Does the code run as expected on *any* other computer that is *not* the development machine?

Comment: I just have to deploy the app to one user and the app is executing on user computer but data is not displaying in any jtable , same is working fine on my pc(development machine)...